# Reverse complement SOME sequences in fasta file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I've been reading lots of helpful posts about reverse complementing sequences, but I've got what seems to be an unusual request. I'm working in bash and I have DNA sequences in fasta format in my stdout that I'd like to pass on down the pipe. The seemingly unusual bit is that I'm trying to reverse complement SOME of those sequences, so that the output has all the sequences in the same direction (for multiple sequence alignment later).

My fasta headers end in either "C" or "+". I'd like to reverse complement the ones that end in "C". Here's a little subset:

```
>chr1:86214203-86220231+
CTGGTGGTACAGCTACATTGTACCATAAAACTTATTCATATTAAAACTTA
TTTATATGTACCTCAAAAGATTAAACTGGGAGATAAGGTGTGGCATTTTT
>chr1:84518073-84524089C
caccttagagataatgaagtatattcagaatgtagaacattctataagac
aactgacccaatatcttttaaaaagtcaatgccatgttaaaaataaaaag
```

I know there are lots of ways to reverse complement out there, like:

```
echo ACCTTGAAA | tr ACGTacgt TGCAtgca | rev
```

and

```
seqtk seq -r in.fa > out.fa
```

But I'm not sure how to do this for only those sequences that have a C at the end of the header. I think awk or sed is probably the ticket, but I'm at a loss as to how to actually code it. I can get the sequence headers with awk, like:

```
awk '/^>/ { print $0 }'
```

```
>chr1:84518073-84524089C
>chr1:86214203-86220231+
```

But if someone could help me figure out how to turn that awk statement into one that asks "if the last character in the header has a C, do this!" that would be great!

Edited to add:
I was so tired when I made this post, I apologize for not including my desired output. Here is what I'd like to output to look like, using my little example:

```
>chr1:86214203-86220231+
CTGGTGGTACAGCTACATTGTACCATAAAACTTATTCATATTAAAACTTA
TTTATATGTACCTCAAAAGATTAAACTGGGAGATAAGGTGTGGCATTTTT
>chr1:84518073-84524089C
ctttttatttttaacatggcattgactttttaaaagatattgggtcagtt
gtcttatagaatgttctacattctgaatatacttcattatctctaaggtg
```

You can see the sequence that ends in + is unchanged, but the sequence with a header that ends in C is reverse complemented.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output for the sample input shown?

Comment: try `awk '/>/ && /C$/ {print}' src.fasta`

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Use the libraries specifically suited for the task, and designed to handle fasta format and all sorts of special cases such as partly degenerate nucleotides, etc. For example, use `biopython`: https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.Seq.reverse_complement . You can install biopython, for example, using `conda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An earlier answer (by Ed Morton) uses a self-contained `awk` procedure to selectively reverse-complement sequences following a comment line ending with "C". Although I think that to be the best approach, I will offer an alternative approach that might have wider applicability.

The procedure here uses `awk`'s `system()` function to send data extracted from the fasta file in `awk` to the shell where the sequence  can be processed by any of the many shell applications existing for sequence manipulation.

I have defined an `awk` user function to pass the isolated sequence from `awk` to the shell. It can be called from any part of the awk procedure:

```
function processSeq(s)
 {system("echo \"" s "\" |  tr ACGTacgt TGCAtgca | rev ");}
```

The argument of the `system` function is a string containing the command you would type into terminal to achieve the desired outcome (in this case I've used one of the example reverse-complement routines mentioned in the question). The parts to note are the correct escaping of quote marks that are to appear in the shell command, and the variable `s` that will be substituted for the sequence string assigned to it when the function is called. The value of `s` is concatenated with the strings quoted before and after it in the argument to `system()` shown above.

**isolating the required sequences**

The rest of the procedure addresses how to achieve:

*"if the last character in the header has a C, do this"*

Before making use of shell applications, `awk` needs to isolate the part(s) of the file to process. In general terms, `awk` employs one or more `pattern`/`action` blocks where only `records` (lines by default) that match a given `pattern` are processed by the subsequent `action` commands. For example, the following illustrative procedure performs the `action` of printing the whole line `print $0` if the `pattern`  `/^>/ && /C$/` is true for that line (where `/^>/` looks for ">" at the start of a line and `/C$/` looks for "C" at the end of the same line.:

```
/^>/ && /C$/{ print $0 }
```

For the current needs, the sequence begins on the next record (line) after any record beginning with `>` and ending with `C`. One way of referencing that next line is to set a variable (named `line` in my example) when the `C` line is encountered and establishing a later pattern for the record with numerical value one more than `line` variable.

Because fasta sequences may extend over several lines, we have to accumulate several successive lines following a `C` title line. I have achieved this by concatenating each line following the `C` title line until a record beginning with `>` is encountered again (or until the end of the file is reached, using the `END` block).

In order that sequence lines following a non-`C` title line are ignored, I have used a variable named `flag` with values of either `"do"` or `"ignore"` set when a title record is encountered.

The call to a the custom function `processSeq()` that employs the `system()` command, is made at the beginning of a `C` title `action` block *if* the variable `seq` holds an accumulated sequence (and in the `END` block for relevant sequences that occur at the end of the file where there will be no title line).

**Test file and procedure**

A modified version of your example fasta was used to test the procedure. It contains an extra relevant `C` record with three and-a-bit lines instead of two, and an extra irrelevant `+` record.

***seq.fasta:***

```
>chr1:86214203-86220231+
CTGGTGGTACAGCTACATTGTACCATAAAACTTATTCATATTAAAACTTA
TTTATATGTACCTCAAAAGATTAAACTGGGAGATAAGGTGTGGCATTTTT
>chr1:84518073-84524089C
caccttagagataatgaagtatattcagaatgtagaacattctataagac
aactgacccaatatcttttaaaaagtcaatgccatgttaaaaataaaaag
>chr1:86214203-86220231+
CTGGTGGTACAGCTACATTGTACCATAAAACTTATTCATATTAAAACTTA
TTTATATGTACCTCAAAAGATTAAACTGGGAGATAAGGTGTGGCATTTTT
>chranotherC
aatgaagtatattcagaatgtagaacattaactgacccgccatgttaatc
aatatctataagaccttttaaaaagcaccttagagattcaataaagtcag
gaagtatattcagaatgtagaacattaactgactaagaccttttaacatg
gcattgact
```

***procedure***

```
awk '

/^>/ && /C$/{
  if (length(seq)>0) {processSeq(seq); seq="";} 
  line=NR; print $0; flag="do"; next;
  } 
  
/^>/ {line=NR; flag="ignore"}
  
NR>1 && NR==(line+1) && (flag=="do"){seq=seq $0; line=NR; next} 
 
function processSeq(s)
 {system("echo \"" s "\" |  tr ACGTacgt TGCAtgca | rev ");}
 
END { if (length(seq)>0) processSeq(seq);} 

' seq.fasta
```

***output***

```
>chr1:84518073-84524089C
ctttttatttttaacatggcattgactttttaaaagatattgggtcagttgtcttatagaatgttctacattctgaatatacttcattatctctaaggtg
>chranotherC
agtcaatgccatgttaaaaggtcttagtcagttaatgttctacattctgaatatacttcctgactttattgaatctctaaggtgctttttaaaaggtcttatagatattgattaacatggcgggtcagttaatgttctacattctgaatatacttcatt
```

Tested using GNU Awk 5.1.0 on a Raspberry Pi 400.

**performance note**

Because calling `sytstem()` creates a sub shell, this process will be slower than a self-contained `awk` procedure. It might be useful where existing shell routines are available or tricky to reproduce with custom awk routines.

**Edit: modification to include unaltered `+` records**

This version has some repetition of earlier blocks, with minor changes, to handle printing of the lines that are not to be reverse-complemented (the changes should be self-explanatory if the main explanations were understood)

```
  awk '

/^>/ && /C$/{
  if (length(seq)>0 && flag=="do") {processSeq(seq)} else {print seq} seq="";line=NR; print $0; flag="do"; next;
  } 
  
/^>/ {if (length(seq)>0 && flag=="do") {processSeq(seq)} else {print seq} seq=""; print $0; line=NR; flag="ignore"}
  
NR>1 && NR==(line+1){seq=seq $0; line=NR; next} 

function processSeq(s)
 {system("echo \"" s "\" |  tr ACGTacgt TGCAtgca | rev ");}
 
END { if (length(seq)>0 && flag=="do") {processSeq(seq)} else {print seq}} 

' seq.fasta
```

Comment: idk if these "fasta" files can get large but if they can then it's worth mentioning that that'd spawn a subshell for every call to system() so it'd be orders of magnitude slower than implementing tr and rev internally in the awk script. It obviously also relies on `rev` existing on the system and that's not a mandatory POSIX tool.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, I was worried a little about that as fasta files can have thousands of records. I've been leafing through *Effective awk programming* and can't see an obvious way to apply `close()` or similar for a `system()` call as one might for file writes or pipes (I'd half hoped it was automatically dealt with). I'd appreciate a pointer to add to the answer if you can suggest something. I rarely use `system()` but there are so many bash tools for fasta, I thought it might be useful here. Thanks.

Comment: `system()` doesn't return until the command it spawns a subshell to call is finished (otherwise it couldn't return that commands exit status as it does) so there's no use for `close()` with `system()`. The time for `close()` with an external command call is if you open a pipe like `"date" | getline; ... close("date")` instead of calling `system("date")`. Either way awk spawns a subshell so it can't be noticeably sped up even if you put the command in the background (``system("date &")``) as the command will typically run in the blink of an eye, it's spawning a subshell that's slow.

Comment: Having said that, with GNU awk you have co-processes which might speed this up a bit by reducing how many subshells get spawned, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO, but I haven't really thought that through.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'd got the idea in my head that is was like piping but I suppose its no different to typing commands into terminal one after the other, slower but unlikely to break due to too many records.

Comment: Hi @DavePritlove, your code does work (thank you!!), but I would also like to print the unaltered "+" strands. I apologize for not including my desired output, but I have edited the post to include that now. Also, these fasta files are thousands of lines, and there are hundreds of files, so I am a bit concerned about the speed. For my example, though, this is very close!

Comment: @Doda I've edited my answer with a modified version that will print the `+` records also. The sequence lines are no longer fixed length lines but continuous strings as it was easier to modify the existing routines that required single strings. Regarding speed, it's a case of suck-it-and-see. I would not expect the procedure to break, it may just take a while if the files are very large.

Comment: @DavePritlove The sequence lines don't need to be fixed, all continuous is just fine. However, I just tested your modified version and it appears to reverse complement the "+" strands as well. I'm looking for those sequences to remain unchanged. Thank you!!

Comment: @Doda my mistake, will fix shortly

Comment: should be ok now

Comment: @DavePritlove this is sooo close! It is perfect, except the very last "+" sequence is still being reverse complemented. I triple-checked. The 2 "C" strands are reverse complemented, the first 2 "+" strands are unaltered, but the last "+" strand is reverse complemented. Any idea how that could happen?

Comment: I'd forgotten to modify the END block that deals with the last record. Should be fine now

Comment: We got it! And thank goodness, I was about to throw this whole idea in the trash. Thank you for your perseverance! May you live a long life.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^>/ {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    head = $0
    tail = ""
    next
}
{ tail = ( tail == "" ? "" : tail ORS ) $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt(    type) {
    type = substr(head,length(head),1)
    tail = ( type == "C" ? rev( tr( tail, "ACGTacgt TGCAtgca" ) ) : tail )
    print head ORS tail
}

function tr(oldStr,trStr,   i,lgth,char,newStr) {
    if ( !_trSeen[trStr]++ ) {
        lgth = (length(trStr) - 1) / 2
        for ( i=1; i<=lgth; i++ ) {
            _trMap[trStr,substr(trStr,i,1)] = substr(trStr,lgth+1+i,1)
        }
    }
    lgth = length(oldStr)
    for (i=1; i<=lgth; i++) {
        char = substr(oldStr,i,1)
        newStr = newStr ( (trStr,char) in _trMap ? _trMap[trStr,char] : char )
    }
    return newStr
}

function rev(oldStr,    i,lgth,char,newStr) {
    lgth = length(oldStr)
    for ( i=1; i<=lgth; i++ ) {
        char = substr(oldStr,i,1)
        newStr = char newStr
    }
    return newStr
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>chr1:86214203-86220231+
CTGGTGGTACAGCTACATTGTACCATAAAACTTATTCATATTAAAACTTA
TTTATATGTACCTCAAAAGATTAAACTGGGAGATAAGGTGTGGCATTTTT
>chr1:84518073-84524089C
ctttttatttttaacatggcattgactttttaaaagatattgggtcagtt
gtcttatagaatgttctacattctgaatatacttcattatctctaaggtg
```

Comment: In fasta format, all the lines after the `>` information row (up to the next >) are interpreted as the concatenation of the lines (as if there were no line breaks). So the sequence needing reversing is caccttag..//..tataagacaactgac ..//.. aaaag. Otherwise, I think you've interpreted exactly what he wants.

Comment: @DavePritlove Thanks. I'm not entirely sure what that means so I'll wait for the OP to provide the expected output if I got it wrong.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton , I have updated my post with my expected output. It is a bit different than the output you provided (sorry for trying to make you guess). Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

Comment: @EdMorton this looks perfect, but *embarrassingly* I am not able to figure out how to insert it into my pipe! The data I used in my example is my stdout. Is this supposed to be saved in a different script called "tst.awk" , which I would then call in my pipe? or should it work directly inside my pipe? I am familiar with the tr and rev functions, are you re-defining those for this specific use case? I apologize for being such a noob, but can you help me figure out how to invoke this?

Comment: I'm creating awk functions named tr and rev that mimic the function of the Unix tools of the same name. If you're running some tool named `foo` that produces the output you want that awk script to work on then you just do `foo | awk 'script'` instead of `awk 'script' file`, same as with almost any other Unix tool. Or `foo | awk -f tst.awk` instead of `awk -f tst.awk file` if your awk script is stored in a file named `tst.awk` as I show in my answer for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE ':a;p;/^>.*C$/!b
         :b;n;/^>/ba;s/^/\n/;y/ACGTacgt/TGCAtgca/
         :c;tc;/\n$/{s///p;bb};s/(.*)\n(.)/\2\1\n/;tc' file
```

Print the current line and then inspect it.

If the line does not begin with `>` and end with `C`, bail out and repeat.

Otherwise, fetch the next line and if it begins with `>`, repeat the above line.

Otherwise, insert a newline (to use as a pivot point when reversing the line), complement the code of the line using a translation command. Then set about reversing the line, character by character until the inserted newline makes its way to the end of the line.

Remove the newline, print the result and repeat the line above.

N.B. The `n` command will terminate the script when it is executed after the last line has been read.

---

Since the OP has amended the ouput, another solution is when the whole of the sequence is complemented and then reversed. Here is another solution that I believe follows these criteria.

```
sed -nE ':a;p;/^>.*C$/!b
         :b;n;/^>/!{H;$!bb};x;y/ACGTacgt\n/TGCAtgca%/;s/%/\n/
         :c;tc;s/\n$//;td;s/(.*)\n(.)/\2\1\n/;tc
         :d;y/%/\n/;p;z;x;$!ba' file
```

Comment: Hi @potong , I really like the short and sweetness of this option, but it doesn't work as expected. It does change the C sequences, but it's not a reverse complementing that is happening. I have updated my post with my desired output, if you have the time to look at this again I would appreciate it, thank you